# zsh printing escape characters to log

Tags: linux, vim, zsh

I recently changed my default shell to zsh from bash. I'm using linux.

When I redirect the output from a zsh script to a log file and then open that log file with vim I get a bunch of escape characters printed, along with pretty much all of the commands that I wrote.

For example, in the script I have

```
printf "\nFinished at "
date
```

if I cat the log file that line looks like

```
Finished at Wed Apr 28 13:58:30 CDT 2021
```

but if I vim into the log file it looks like:

```
Finished at ^[]2;date^G^[]1;^GWed Apr 28 13:58:30 CDT 2020
```

Using less instead of vim shows the same thing, minus the `^[]` (but with the `^G`).

The first line in that log file is a big mess of the commands from the script (that I didn't want printed) along with the escape characters.

I'm guessing that this is something I can fix with `stty`, but I try adding

```
stty -echoctl
```

to my `.zshrc` but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: How do you "redirect the output from a zsh script to a log file"?

Comment: The escape characters look like the sequence used to change the title bar  of a terminal window. `cat` writes the bytes directly to the terminal, which interprets them as instructions rather than displaying them. `vim` simply displays them, and `less` apparently does something in between. Is `date` itself a wrapper around the usual command?